# How can I search symbols with partial words in VS Code with IntelliSense?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, fuzzy-search

**How can I search symbols (e.g. class) with partial words in VS Code and IntelliSense?**

In VS Code, it's possible to look for files with partial words. For example, it's possible to locate a file `this_is_my_best_class.py` with file search and typing `thisbest`. Similar doesn't seem to work for symbols though.

Let's say you have a class called `MyBestInheritedIntelliSenseClass` and you want to locate that from your work space. Is there a way to look for a symbol with typing something like `BestIntelSen` instead of typing e.g. the whole `MyBestInheritedIntelliSen`?

I'm using VS Code (v1.41.1, Windows) and Python extension (v2020.1.58038).

I have used PyCharm for a very long time and now changed to VS Code to see what it is about. Looking for symbols as explained above is how I would do it in PyCharm and - as an old habit - would use similar with VS Code. What is the right way to do it?

---

Here's the same with screenshots. This is the class I could look for (VS Code):

[image]

This is what I would like to type (VS Code):

[image]

This is what I would like to see it (this is from PyCharm):

[image]

And this is the same working for files in VS Code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the `Go to Symbol in Editor...` command (the one where the search input starts with "`@`"), fuzzy searching is purportedly supported by VS Code. See [Allow fuzzy result on searching symbol in file #62435](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62435):

> This is now actually working. Since a few months outline uses the same fuzzy score algorithm IntelliSense sense does and the samples should you have listed should now work. please file individual issues for cases that don't work well. - [jrieken](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62435#issuecomment-545487136)

For the `Go to Symbol in Workspace` command (the one where the search input starts with "`#`"), fuzzy searching needs support on a *per-extension* basis. This is mentioned in at least two issue tickets on the VS Code GitHub repo:

In [Ctrl+T (Go to Symbol in Workspace...) does not support fuzzy search
#156865](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156865)

> Previously, [#106788](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106788), [#62435](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62435), [#33746](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33746). I think we just pass the query over to extensions and they have to support this to return the results, its not on us. This is different for symbol search in the file where we get all results iirc. - [bpasero](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156865#issuecomment-1216156910)

And in [Add fuzzy search to search by symbol
#33746](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33746):

> The sorting and ranking (in the UI) is actually using our fuzzy search logic but that only helps when the extension that provides the data uses a similar relaxed algorithm. In the jsdoc we have the following [statement](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2166211fccaf8a79048ff645552df940dfd6f41a/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L2689-L2707)
>
> > - The `query`-parameter should be interpreted in a *relaxed way* as the editor will apply its own highlighting and scoring on the results. A good rule of thumb is to match case-insensitive and to simply check that the characters of *query* appear in their order in a candidate symbol. Don't use prefix, substring, or similar strict matching.
>
> There is not much more VS Code can do as it is only rendering results that extension providing. Therefore closing as 'caused by extension' and with a pretty please to file this in the context of each extension. - [jrieken](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33746#issuecomment-545340146)

Here are a few of those extension-specific issue tickets for this feature that I was able to find through related GitHub links and by googling "`github issues "go to symbol" workspace fuzzy`" and "`github issues "go to symbol in workspace" fuzzy`":

- `microsoft/python-language-server`: ["Open symbol by name" not fuzzy matching #697](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/697)
- `microsoft/pylance-release`: [Symbol search matching in middle of word, or with fuzzy matching
  #362](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/362)
- `microsoft/vscode-cpptools`: [Allow "fuzzy" substring symbol search, similar to Go To File (CTRL+P) and Completion
  #2751](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2751)
- `bmewburn/vscode-intelephense`: [Fuzzy search for "Go To Symbol in Workspace"? #21](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/21) and [Wider fuzzy search in "Go to symbol in workspace"? #2205](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2205)
- `microsoft/vscode-go`: [Fuzzy search of workspace symbols #2950](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2950)
- `rubyide/vscode-ruby`: [Go To Symbol In Workspace not working with fuzzy search #653](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/653)